# ngx-i18nsupport no es soportado para angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, i18n

estoy usando  ngx-i18nsupport  para poder hacer el merge  de los archivos message.en.xlf
pero esto ya no es sopportado en angular 12
hay una manera similar para hacer el merge de los archivos sin que se pierda las  traducciones anteriores
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: parece ser que en el 12 funciona, para el 13 no https://github.com/martinroob/ngx-i18nsupport/issues/197

Answer (score 1):

Las opciones que usas están obsoletas. Para que te funcione debes usar [las actuales](https://angular.io/cli/extract-i18n). Prueba así:

```
ng extract-i18n PROJECT --format=xlf2 --output-path=i18n && ng run PROJECT:xliffmerge
```